# How to call managed bean in h:outputLink when opening new page

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a `h:outputLink` which opens new JSF page and sends `h:param`.

```
<h:outputLink id="lnkHidden" action="#{HistoryLinkController.linkValue("test")}" value="HistoryLink.xhtml" style="display:none">
<f:param name="id" value="#{item.aSessionID}" />
</h:outputLink>
```

I want when I click it to send a value to a second managed bean. I tried to implement it with `action="#{HistoryLinkController.linkValue("test")}"` but I get error. Is there any attribute that I can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 5):

Try using a `<h:commandLink>` in the following way and it should work fine

```
<h:commandLink id="hLink" value="History" action="#{HistoryLinkController.linkValue}" >         
 <f:param name="sessID" value="#{item.aSessionID}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

and the bean "HistoryLinkController" should have a method like

```
public String linkValue(){
   // get "sessID" from FacesContext
   ...
   return "/HistoryLink.xhtml";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace h:outputLink into h:commandLink.

Answer (score 1):

I have also tried to navigate to some view along with passing a value to another bean already but I didn't get it. But what I got is---
U can remain in the same bean class if possible, and use `navigation rules` in `faces-config.xml` for navigating to another page.

And In ajax, `action` will be called earlier than its `actionListener`.

Hope it helps you finding a way...

Comment: At the end how did you solve the problem with navigation and passing a value?

Comment: U want something like clicking on menuItem of some row of first view and then it should navigate to other page which will display the details according to selected value from first page. isn't it.....

Comment: @downvoter : It would be good to point out the problem ......
I got it working and till now i did not even explained all,   I was explaining only what is required to OP...